# Change mailchimp template html with API

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Hi I'm trying to use Mailchimp library with [mailchimp php sdk](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api). I'm trying to change the HTML content with api call using this.

```
$MailChimp = new \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp('api key');
$MailChimp->verify_ssl = false;
$MailChimp->patch('templates/temp id', [
    'name' => 'my template',
    'html' => '<p>dsd</p>'
]);


if ($MailChimp->success()) {
     print_r($result);    
} else {
     echo $MailChimp->getLastError();
}
```

since we can change the name without any issue it seems like **the issue relies on**  `'html' => '<p>dsd</p>'`. It would be great help if someone can check.

error message I got is,

> 400: The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific
>   details, see the 'errors' array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error happens when an API request attempts to change a template that doesn't allow custom HTML. On the *templates* page in MailChimp, any template that's labeled as 'Drag and drop' will fail to update the HTML with an API request. It needs to be labeled as 'Code your own'.

The format can't change once it's set, so you'll have to create a new template and choose 'Code your own' on the creation page, then it will allow the `html` request parameter to be updated using the API.

Also, if you need to use the same design from your old template, you can export it as HTML, but the drag and drop features won't work when you import it to the new template.

Hope this helps!

Comment: After hours of investigation, I discovered that existing MailChimp campaigns created via MailChimp's UI end up with content_type "template" and cannot have their content updated via the API. 

Only campaigns with content_type "html" can. This is only set by switching the campaign to "code your own" in the template screen OR, more importantly, creating a new campaign VIA the API (it will initially have content_type "template") and update it with content (it will switch to content_type "html")